# start-stop-daemon with --background vs running using & option

Tags: linux, shell, init.d, start-stop-daemon

What is the difference in running a process in background using start-stop-daemon with --background option and using with &?Which option is best and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `start-stop-daemon --background` then start-stop-daemon will fork off a process to run in the background and then start-stop-daemon immediately exits. Among other things this means you can check the exit status of start-stop-daemon.

If you use `start-stop-daemon &` then the shell forks off a background process and runs start-stop-daemon in it. You won't be able to check its exit status as it won't actually exit (until the thing it runs exits).

In most cases `start-stop-daemon --background` is a better choice.

Comment: i still don't have much clarity on what makes start-stop-daemon --background better option than & .

Comment: Are you running it directly on the command line or are you using it in a script (e.g., a startup script)? 
If you're running it on the command line it doesn't make a lot of difference unless you want to leave it running even after you exit the shell. In that case start-stop-daemon will do the necessary work to make sure the daemon stays running in the background after the shell exits. if you use & then you need to take other steps (e.g., nohup)

Comment: In a startup script you probably want to have start-stop-daemon do things like create a pidfile and stuff. And you want start-stop-daemon to be able to kill the process when things shut down. That all works more reliably if you use --background.

Comment: I am using it in startup script with --background option.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `&` option for making a background job.  However, on the occasions that I forget to include the `&`, I use the Ctrl-Z command to stop the job and then enter `bg` to move the stopped command into the background.

While I have not observed any difference in the approaches (with the exception that `&` can be used *in* a script).  A colleague of mine was very pleased to find out about the Ctrl-Z option of suspending a job.  He claimed that he had some tasks where that "worked better".

If you want to learn more about Ctrl-Z and `bg`, look for bash job control.